# undefined and NaN, convert to boolean value implicitly vs explicitly

Tags: javascript, boolean, undefined, nan

I'm currently learning javascript by following the book "you dont know js".

In the section "[type & grammer](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md)", when discussing implicit vs explicit boolean convertion, the author mentioned

> ```
> //come up with a function that make sure only one argument is truthy
>
> //implicit convertion
> function onlyOne() {
>   var sum = 0;
>   for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
>       // skip falsy values. same as treating
>       // them as 0's, but avoids NaN's.
>       if (arguments[i]) {
>           sum += arguments[i];
>       }
>   }
>   return sum == 1;
> }
>
> //explicit convertion
> function onlyOne() {
>   var sum = 0;
>   for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
>       sum += Number( !!arguments[i] );
>   }
>   return sum === 1;
> }
> ```
>
> Is the explicit coercion form of this utility "better"? It does avoid
>   the `NaN` trap as explained in the code comments. But, ultimately, it
>   depends on your needs. I personally think the former version, relying
>   on implicit coercion is more elegant (if you won't be passing
>   `undefined` or `NaN`), and the explicit version is needlessly more
>   verbose.

My question is, what `NaN` trap is the author talking about? I thought when `undefined` and `NaN` is converted to boolean value, regardless of whether it is converted implicitly or explicitly, they both results in `false`. And passing `undefined` and `NaN` to the implicit function is ok, right?

Comment: Well, the first example clearly does not work for all truthy values.

Comment: @MinusFour truthy values are everything except `NaN, undefined, null, +0, -0, "", false", so what kind of truthy value wouldn't work with  the first example?

Comment: Any object, or any non-empty string.

Comment: Well any object that doesn't have a `toPrimitive` that gets you a string.

Comment: @MinusFour ah, yes, even though `if(arguments[i])` will work as expected, inside the `if` statement, we are adding `arguments[i]` directly to `sum`, so if for example, `arguments[i]` is a non empty string, the `sum` will be implicitly converted to a string, which is not what we want

Comment: this is a very poor example of explicit vs implicit boolean value testing.

Comment: The code should either read `if (arguments[i]) sum++`, `sum += +!!arguments[i]` or `sum += Number(Boolean(arguments[i]))` (or possibly leaving the number cast implicit), but not a mix of them.

Answer (score 1):

the 2nd example always avoid NaN,because Number(!!string) and Number(!!object) are both converted to 1 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syzhe.png)

Comment: Sorry,it's always avoid.my bad!

Answer (score 1):

I think that an example of a real explicit check would be...

```
function onlyOne() {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      sum += Boolean( arguments[i] );
  }
  return sum == 1;
}
```

This will of course avoid /  guard against NaN and should return false if no arguments are present; if no arguments are truthy and of course -if more than one arguments are truthy.